# Get vlookup and check whether the value is available or not?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new trying to write vba code using vb. I wrote this code using vba tutorial. Now I have tried to write sample code for output as followed:

Also I am trying to shortcut key for to create macro in vba

```
Sheet 1
Column B
123456

Column E
20/3/2000


Sheet2
Column A
123456

Column D
25/3/2000
```

I am trying to check whether the date is available in sheet2 for "123456" or if it is not available in sheet 2. I have to create output for "123456".
Output should be column like

```
ColumnA
123456
ColumnB
20/3/2000
ColumnC
2
```

My code is :

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim Line As String
Dim LineValues() As Variant
Dim OutputFileNum As Integer
Dim PathName As String
Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim SheetValues() As Variant
Dim rngNums As Range
Dim cmpny As Range
Dim v As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim result As Variant
Dim c As Range, nm As Range

PathName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
OutputFileNum = FreeFile

Open PathName & "\test.csv" For Output Lock Write As #OutputFileNum

Print #OutputFileNum, "test1" & "," & "test2 (dd/MM/yyyy)" & "," & "test3"

End Sub
```

Comment: your code creates a text file?

Comment: Additional Q: Is this more or less everything you need to do? If so, you could do it with VLookup() without VBA.

Comment: I am new bee...I am tried but i dont know how to get vlookup with in the same work sheet without vba